# Modify view in SharePoint Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, web-part, discussion-board

I created a discussion board and would like to hide the new discussion part as well as the views listed below and the line (divider) that is underneath that too.

Is there any kind of code to help in hiding that section?

I'm not sure where to turn to. I've gone down a rabbit hole and can't find anything or anyone who has tried hiding this whole section.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding below custom CSS on the SharePoint page where you have added your web part:

```
<style>
    div.ms-comm-forumContainer div.ms-comm-heroLinkContainer, div.ms-comm-forumContainer div.ms-comm-forumHeaderContainer {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

Use Content Editor or Script Editor web part to add this CSS.

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That helped!